# Hibernate + Derby: Comparisons between 'BOOLEAN' and 'INTEGER' are not supported

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, derby

I have a problem with querying Derby database. I am using Hibernate with JPA. Problem is related (probably) to boolean columns. Each query ends with error:

*org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Comparisons between 'BOOLEAN' and 'INTEGER' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')*

Below you may find sample code and configuration. Samples are simplified for easier reading. Here is my JPA entity:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Task implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    protected long id;

    @Column
    protected boolean deleted;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!this.getClass().equals(object.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        EntityObject other = (EntityObject) object;

        if (this.id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EntityObject[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

My JPA query:

```
SELECT t FROM Task t WHERE deleted = false
```

My JPA configuration:

```
<persistence-unit name="PU1" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/myapp</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

What is wrong? How to fix that? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the data type of Task.deleted in derby? It is a bit of a long shot but maybe hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update is not applying data type changes.

Comment: Task.deleted is boolean in Derby database. Database schema is up-to-date synchronized with entity classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrade didn't helped. Here is valid solution which works for me:

```
import java.sql.Types;
import org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect;

public class DerbyDialect extends DerbyTenSevenDialect {

    public DerbyDialect() {
        // fix Derby dialect boolean data type mapping error
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "INTEGER");
    }
}
```

I guess it is better to configure 'true' and 'false' constants mapping in dialect to Derby data type, but above is good enough for now.

Answer (score 4):

Boolean datatype was added in Derby 10.7, you appear to be using 10.7 or newer so you should use the [`org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/DerbyTenSevenDialect.html) dialect which adds Boolean support.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. What is more for both dialects there is warning in logs: "The DerbyDialect dialect has been deprecated; use one of the version-specific dialects instead". Similar problem is already reported as a bug to Hibernate team: [bug1](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6961?page=com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin%3Afisheye-issuepanel) and [bug2](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7059) Thanks for help - I will try downgrade Derby for now.

Comment: BTW, my Derby version is 10.8.1.2

Answer (score 4):

You have to set your boolean as a parameter:

```
String queryString = "SELECT t FROM Task t WHERE t.deleted = :trueValue";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("trueValue", true);
query.getResultList();
```

Hope it will work for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Used Rafal's approach but also have to add

```
@Override
public String toBooleanValueString(boolean bool) {
    return bool ? "1" : "0";
}
```

in my Dialect. Otherwise it doesn't work under Hibernate 4.2.8.

Also I wasn't be able to specify my dialect explicitly in persistence.xml as my app runs against Oracle and Derby. So I've added a dialect resolver for my dialect:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect_resolvers" value="...DerbyBoolAsIntDialectResolver"/>
```

Resolver itself:

```
public class DerbyBoolAsIntDialectResolver extends AbstractDialectResolver {
    @Override
    protected Dialect resolveDialectInternal(DatabaseMetaData metaData) throws SQLException {
        String databaseName = metaData.getDatabaseProductName();
        int databaseMajorVersion = metaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion();

        if ( "Apache Derby".equals( databaseName ) ) {
            final int databaseMinorVersion = metaData.getDatabaseMinorVersion();
            if ( databaseMajorVersion > 10 || ( databaseMajorVersion == 10 && databaseMinorVersion >= 7 ) ) {
                return new DerbyBoolAsIntDialect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, my 'deleted ' column is boolean in derby and number in Oracle. Can you explain why this needs to be done?